# how to groupby and aggregate dynamic columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
code    tank     nozzle_1   nozzle_2    nozzle_var    nozzle_sale
123     1        1          1           10            10
123     1        2          2           12            10
123     2        1          1           10            10
123     2        2          2           12            10
123     1        1          1           10            10
123     2        2          2           12            10
```

Now, I want to generate cumulative sum of all the columns grouping over tank and take out the last observation. nozzle_1 and nozzle_2 columns are dynamic, it could be nozzle_3, nozzle_4....nozzle_n etc. I am doing following in pandas to get the cumsum

```
## Below code for calculating cumsum of dynamic columns nozzle_1 and nozzle_2
cols= df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat='nozzle_\d+$', regex=True)] 
df.assign(**df.groupby('tank')[cols].agg(['cumsum'])\
          .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.map('_'.join), axis=1, inplace=False)))
## nozzle_sale_cumsum is static column
df[nozzle_sale_cumsum] = df.groupby('tank')['nozzle_sale'].cumsum()
```

From above code I will get cumsum of following columns

```
  tank  nozzle_1  nozzle_2  nozzle_var  nozzle_1_cumsum  nozzle_2_cumsum   nozzle_sale_cumsum
  1         1         1          10                1                1      10
  1         2         2          12                3                3      20
  2         1         1          10                1                1      10
  2         2         2          12                3                3      20
  1         1         1          10                4                4      30
  2         2         2          12                5                5      30
```

Now, I want to get last values of all 3 cumsum columns grouping over tank. I can do it with following code in pandas, but it is hard coded with column names.

```
 final_df= df.groupby('tank').agg({'nozzle_1_cumsum':'last',
                                   'nozzle_2_cumsum':'last',
                                   'nozzle_sale_cumsum':'last',
                                   }).reset_index()
```

Problem with above code is nozzle_1_cumsum and nozzle_2_cumsum is hard coded which is not the case. How can I do this in pandas with dynamic columns.

Comment: {colName:'last' for colName in df.columns[-3:]}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
df.filter(regex='_cumsum').groupby(df['tank']).last()
```

Output:

```
      nozzle_1_cumsum  nozzle_2_cumsum  nozzle_sale_cumsum
tank                                                      
1                   4                4                  30
2                   5                5                  30
```

You can also replace `df.filter(...)` by, e.g., `df.iloc[:,-3:]` or `df[col_names]`.

Comment: I also need tank in it. When I do reset_index() it does not give me a tank.

Comment: Try passing `as_index=True` to `groupby`.

Comment: I did that, but does not give me tank.

Comment: I see the problem, replace `tail(1)` with `last`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you :)